# getLocation() function failing inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, location, locationlistener

Here's my breakdown: I have a class called UserLocation where I perform all Location events. Within this class I have a function, `public Location getLocation(Context context)` , where I check for Location providers, get locations from all available providers, and return the most accurate. Now I want to use this function inside an `AsyncTask` in my SplashScreen Activity. I have been reading several resources that I need to call a `Looper.prepare()` at the beginning of my `doInBackground` method and `Looper.loop()` at the end of the method. However, I cannot get it to work properly. I have scanned my logcat and the line that sticks out to me is Looper.loop() line: 137

Splash Activity: (modified slightly to avoid garbage)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);


    new LoadData().execute();
}

class LoadData extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void> {

        private final int prgTitle[] = { R.string.Checking_Service,
                                                R.string.fetching_location,
                                                R.string.Location_got,
                                                R.string.Connect_Database};
        private final int prgNums[] = {0, 10, 25, 50, 85,};
        private int index;

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {

            int max = 0;
            for (final int p : prgNums){
            max += p;
            }

            pBar.setMax(max);
            index = 0;

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

            if(usrLoc.canGetLocation = true){
            usrLoc.getLocation(mContext);   
            }


            if(usrLoc.latitude  != Double.NaN){
                //do stuff
            }


            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... loadingValues) {
            pBarText.setText(prgTitle[index]);
            pBar.incrementProgressBy(prgNums[index]);
            ++index;
            publishProgress();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(){

            usrLoc.stopUsingGPS();
        }

    }
```

EDIT: LogCat Posted

```
12-10 14:26:00.434: D/AndroidRuntime(894): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
12-10 14:26:00.434: D/AndroidRuntime(894): CheckJNI is ON
12-10 14:26:01.272: D/AndroidRuntime(894): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-10 14:26:01.312: D/AndroidRuntime(894): Shutting down VM
12-10 14:26:01.332: I/AndroidRuntime(894): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-10 14:26:01.342: D/dalvikvm(894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 462K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
12-10 14:26:01.342: D/dalvikvm(894): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-10 14:26:01.932: D/AndroidRuntime(907): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
12-10 14:26:01.932: D/AndroidRuntime(907): CheckJNI is ON
12-10 14:26:02.864: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-10 14:26:02.892: I/ActivityManager(91): Force stopping package com.book.swap uid=10040
12-10 14:26:02.892: W/ActivityManager(91): Force removing ActivityRecord{41785ec8 com.book.swap/.SplashScreen}: app died, no saved state
12-10 14:26:02.892: I/Process(91): Sending signal. PID: 877 SIG: 9
12-10 14:26:02.922: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2
12-10 14:26:02.992: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10005, 1) failed with errno -2
12-10 14:26:03.022: I/ActivityManager(91): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.book.swap/.SplashScreen} from pid 907
12-10 14:26:03.073: I/WindowManager(91): createSurface Window{41af7978 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-10 14:26:03.092: W/WindowManager(91): Failure taking screenshot for (240x394) to layer 21005
12-10 14:26:03.102: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
12-10 14:26:03.152: I/AndroidRuntime(907): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-10 14:26:03.163: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 485K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-10 14:26:03.163: D/jdwp(907): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
12-10 14:26:03.163: D/dalvikvm(907): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-10 14:26:03.191: D/dalvikvm(918): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-10 14:26:03.202: I/WindowManager(91): createSurface Window{41a24bd0 Starting com.book.swap paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-10 14:26:03.222: I/ActivityManager(91): Start proc com.book.swap for activity com.book.swap/.SplashScreen: pid=918 uid=10040 gids={3003}
12-10 14:26:03.522: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(91): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2
12-10 14:26:03.662: W/ActivityThread(918): Application com.book.swap is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-10 14:26:03.672: I/System.out(918): Sending WAIT chunk
12-10 14:26:03.682: I/dalvikvm(918): Debugger is active
12-10 14:26:03.872: I/System.out(918): Debugger has connected
12-10 14:26:03.872: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:04.072: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:04.202: I/WindowManager(91): createSurface Window{41adaa20 Waiting For Debugger paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-10 14:26:04.272: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:04.498: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:04.692: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:04.904: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:05.102: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:05.122: W/InputManagerService(91): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@417c64e8
12-10 14:26:05.355: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:05.619: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:05.822: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:06.065: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:06.287: I/System.out(918): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-10 14:26:06.513: I/System.out(918): debugger has settled (1427)
12-10 14:26:13.132: W/ActivityManager(91): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-10 14:26:13.597: W/ActivityManager(91): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{418af8c8 com.book.swap/.SplashScreen}
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91): problem reading network stats
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:771)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:610)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     ... 10 more
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
12-10 14:31:31.391: A/NetworkStats(91):     ... 13 more
```

Comment: Also assume there are no errors. I realize it appears some variables are not initialized, but I assure you all variable are initialized and Eclipse claims the code is error free.

Comment: what is `usrLoc`? also this `usrLoc.canGetLocation = true` is wrong. what makes you think you need to use `Looper.prepare`?

Comment: You should take out the `Looper` stuff and post your logcat (that shouldn't be needed in `AsyncTask`). Also, is your task being called from a background `Thread` or from the `UI`? Your second `param` in your `AsyncTask` (`Integer`) should be the `param` your `onProgressUpdate()` takes but they are different in your code.

Comment: `UserLocation usrLoc = UserLocation.getInstance();` `usrLoc` is just a variable that references the UserLocation class. What is incorrect about the statement? I will edit the post with the logcat.

Comment: @Derok8 it is incorrect because you are setting that to true and equating it, if you wand to see if something is true you need to eiteer do `==` or simple just put `usrLoc.canGetLocation` in the if statement. what you are doing will always cause it to pass the test

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I am surprised I didn't catch it. LogCat is posted. I hope it is what you need I am honestly not very good at reading it.

Comment: Sorry took me second I preemptively posted that comment

Comment: the log does not show any errors in it....

Comment: From the looks of it, you aren't getting a crash. Is the app just not starting at all? I don't think this is related to your code at all but an issue with your IDE and or project configuration

Comment: there were a series of errors that were thrown about 3 minutes after the app crashed. does it have anything to do with the fact that I am testing on an emulator? I am waiting for my test phone to arrive which is why I have to use the emulator.

Comment: So did it actual crash or did it never start?

Comment: The app shows I get a blank white screen with the title bar and then nothing happens and the emulator minimizes and I get `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1955` tab in my IDE window.